# Summarizing data in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to LINQ and trying to aggregate some data.
My data is in below format

```
CURRENCY PRODUCT LEVEL1 LEVEL2  VALUE

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.2 10000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.2 3000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.2 2000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.2 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.2 10000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.2 3000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.2 2000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.2 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.3 10000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.3 3000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.3 2000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.3 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.3 10000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.3 3000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.3 2000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.3 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.2 2000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.2 5000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.2 7000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.2 9000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.2 2000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.2 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.2 2000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.2 5000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.3 7000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.3 9000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.3 2000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.3 1000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.3 2000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.3 5000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.3 7000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.3 9000
```

I would like to summarize the VALUE in this data by LEVEL1 and LEVEL2 and PRODUCT.
So after grouping and summarizing the expected result would be as below.

```
CURRENCY  PRODUCT   LEVEL1  LEVEL2  VALUE

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.2 21000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.2 16000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.2 18000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.2 10000

USDJPY  OPTION  100 0.3 21000

USDJPY  OPTION  101 0.3 21000

USDJPY  FWD 100 0.3 14000

USDJPY  FWD 101 0.3 18000
```

Basically, the result should have only one row or object for each combination of product, level1 and level2 and value should be sum of values.
The resulting data should be in the same structure (or same columns) as the initial data.
I've tried using group by and Sum but haven't been able to do it correctly.

Can someone please help me with the LINQ operations in C# to get this result.

I'm storing this data as a list of objects of below class:

```
public class RiskData
{

    public string CcyPair { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }

    public string SpotLvl { get; set; }
    public string VolLvl  { get; set; }
    public double Risk { get; set; }

    public RiskData(string ccypair, string product, string spotlvl, string vollvl, double risk)
    {
        CcyPair = ccypair;
        Product = product;
        SpotLvl = spotlvl;
        VolLvl = vollvl;
        Risk = risk;

    }

}
 var result = from data in riskdata
                     group by data.SpotLvl
                     select new RiskData(???)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this guy? He's clearly new - offer advice on how to improve the question instead of downvoting please.

Comment: How do you load the data into C#? Do you load it into objects or just a simple 2D-array?

Comment: Thanks. I'm loading it as a list of objects of below class.
 public class RiskData
    {
       
        public string CcyPair { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }

        public string SpotLvl { get; set; }
        public string VolLvl  { get; set; }
        public double Risk { get; set; }       
      
    }

Comment: Ok - now the next question (which the downvoters should have asked) - 1) what have you tried so far? and 2) what error are you getting?

Comment: We cannot help you with your linq unless we know the declaration of  the class representing your objects.

Comment: @Ravi Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to understand what we expect from questions posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language construct you are missing is using an anonymous type as a group key:

```
   var result = risksObjects.GroupBy(g => new { g.Product, g.Level1, g.Level2 } )
                    .Select(
                        g => new { 
                            Key = g.Key,
                            Total = g.Sum(r => r.Risk)
                        }
                    )
                    .ToArray();
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{

public class RiskData { 
     public string CcyPair { get; set; } 
     public string Product { get; set; } 
     public string SpotLvl { get; set; } 
     public string VolLvl { get; set; } 
     public double Risk { get; set; }

     public double Level1
     {
         get
         {
             double result;
             if (double.TryParse(SpotLvl, out result))
                 return result;
             else
                 return 0;
         }
     }

     public double Level2
     {
         get
         {
             double result;
             if (double.TryParse(VolLvl, out result))
                 return result;
             else
                 return 0;
         }
     }

     public RiskData(string ccypair, string product, string spotlvl, string vollvl, double risk)
     {
         CcyPair = ccypair;
         Product = product;
         SpotLvl = spotlvl;
         VolLvl = vollvl;
         Risk = risk;
     }
}



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<RiskData> risksObjects = Load();





        var result = risksObjects.GroupBy(g => new { g.Product, g.Level1, g.Level2 } )
                        .Select(
                            g => new { 
                                Key = g.Key,
                                Total = g.Sum(r => r.Risk)
                            }
                        )
                        .ToArray();


        foreach (var r in result)
            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + r.Key + ", Total: " + r.Total);


            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static List<RiskData> Load()
        {
            var result = new List<RiskData>();

//            INSTRUMENT  PORTFOLIO   PRODUCT LEVEL1  LEVEL2  VALUE

result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY","OPTION","100", "0.2",10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY","FWD","100", "0.2",3000));

// just copy/pasted the above two lines a bunch in here...

result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "OPTION", "100", "0.2", 10000));
result.Add(new RiskData("USDJPY", "FWD", "100", "0.2", 3000));



            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan.
I'm transforming/summarizing the initial list of objects so that I've just one object for a combination of product, level1 and level2.
I guess that this will have to done in steps for summarizing by each param.
The problem is once summarized the resulting data structure is different from the initial one.
var result =            from data in riskdata
                         group by data.SpotLvl
                         select new RiskData(???)

Comment: @Ravi - how does that look?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. As you mentioned, I think I didn't specify the requirement clearly. Your code is summarizing level1 and level2. I'm interested in summarizing the VALUE param after grouping by PRODUCT, LEVEL1 and LEVEL2. 
Thanks for your prompt reply !

Comment: @Ravi - updated - I think this is what you're after now - let me know (accept if it is) :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, Nathan!. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem - welcome to Stack Overflow.  The first question is often a learning experience, I hope your next question goes more smoothly :)